# python: searching a text file for values in a list

Tags: python, string, list, csv

im trying to search a large text file for a list of words.  rather than running a command over and over for each word, I thought a list would be easier but I'm not sure how to go about it.  the script below more or less work with the string value but I would like to replace the 'string' below with every value for the 'dict' list.

```
import csv

count = 0
dic = open('dictionary','r') #changed from "dict" in original post
reader = csv.reader(dic)
allRows = [row for row in reader]
with open('bigfile.log','r') in inF:
   for line in inF:
      if 'string' in line: #<---replace the 'string' with dict values
         count += 1
count
```

Comment: Don't name a variable `dict`; it masks the built-in. You can just do `list(reader)` instead of the list comp.

Comment: How many columns does the `dictionary` CSV file contain? What are the column values? What column are you trying to match against.

Comment: I have a few thousand lines with 1 column.  the list is a blacklist of known spam sites.  List looks like what you'd expect, spam.spam.com or whatever.  there are no ',' in the csv file just '\n'

Comment: And your bigfile.log file? Can we split that out on whitespace or similar to isolate the domain names?

Comment: remove white space? That is fine!  I'm all about efficiency and speed.

Comment: I was asking if it was possible to split the lines of `bigfile.log` in any way to make it easy to detect matches. Can you give a few sample lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert your file to a set instead:

```
 with open('dictionary','r') as d:
     sites = set(l.strip() for l in d)
```

Now you can do efficient membership tests per line, *provided you can split your lines*:

```
with open('bigfile.log','r') as inF:
   for line in inF:
       elements = line.split()
       if sites.intersection(elements):
           count += 1
```

Comment: @sixteenornumber: Thanks for the correction; for code changes, it is often just easier to make it a comment, as a minor code typo correction like that is more often than not rejected, as reviewers cannot be expected to know python.